# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: error occurs

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a program that executes commands. I am splitting commands with space.
In a console, if I type `(X 2 C)`   it works as it prints the previous 2 commands and then it Clears all the previous commands.
but if I just want to print previous history commands without clearing commands for `ex) (X 1)` there is a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: `Split[2]` will only succeed without an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` if `Split.length > 2`.  Did you check that `Split.length > 2` first before just assuming that `Split[2]` would succeed?

Comment: What does the error message say? What does your debugger say?

Answer (score 2):

Before accessing `Split[2]` check if `Split.length >2`

Answer (score 2):

When you input `X 1` and split it into an array the resulting array will be `["X" , "1"]`. Since Arrays start at 0 the size of the array is 2 with "X" having the index 0 and "1" the index 1.

By attempting to access `Split[2]` you are trying to access a value which isn't present and an index which is exceeding the length of the array and therefore get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Before tryong to access certain indices you should always make sure that the index you attempt to access is within the size of the array.